# How to get last string character before "."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I know there are several code for this, but still i'm not able to get accurate answer. I want to get the character before ".". I tried given code but its not working. 
For example

```
String Test="~/Images/31/Demo.jpg";

//this code not work

   Test= Test.Substring(0, Test.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Output

```
Test="Demo";
```

Comment: Do you want a single character or some substring? If you want a substring, where should it start?

Comment: it should start just before last occurence of '.'

Comment: The question is worded very strangely. The character before `'.'` in this example is `'o'`. If what you want is the substring *between* the last `'/'` and the last `'.'`, please specify that more clearly. That will probably help you avoid a lot of downvotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No parsing required, use the framework! This is what you really want:

```
String Test="~/Images/31/Demo.jpg";
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Test);
```

Comment: If he wants the character before the dot he want's `o`. Why the path?

Comment: t's not about extension .. i want a substring just before last .'

Comment: @Serv OP states they the character but then writes they want the output to be "Demo". I assume OP meant "word" not character.

Comment: @Subhash do you expect to get "Demo"? If so, this answer is correct.

Comment: @Serv The desired output is `Demo` surely -- the question is worded incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to the substring method is the start index, you want to start where the index of the "." is minus one. The second parameter to the substring method is the length of the returned string from the start index.  If you only want one character you would pass a one for the second parameter.  Try this:

```
Test = Test.Substring(Test.LastIndexOf(".") - 1, 1);
```